# What would be an efficient way to store variable IDs along with values?

Tags: c, data-structures

I am looking to store my data in a data structure which allows me to do the following efficiently:

I have 10 arrays of type 1 and 10 arrays of type 2 with 100 elements each. Each of these array store values of 100 variables. Accompanying these I have 20 arrays containing the corresponding variable IDs.
In total arrays of type 1 store values of 1000 variables and arrays of type 2 store different values of the same 1000 variables.

Now, I need to take a difference of the values of variables in arrays of type 1 from that of arrays of type 2. Let A be the one of the array of type 1. The problem is that variables in A would be spread 10 each across all 10 arrays of type 2.

A hash map would not be useful as I also need to iterate over the values in each array. Any ideas?

Comment: My comment was stupid so I removed it.  Using a hashmap of sorts is probably your best bet, even if you have to use 10 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to do such operations often you might want to construct and index at the program startup (the construction has `O(n^2)` time complexity) once and then refer to it later.

```
struct LookupEntry {
   A *item1;
   B *item2;
};

std::map< IdType, LookupEntry > index;
```

This would allow you to linearly go through arrays of type `A` and get the values from arrays of type `B` in a constant time. You can also subtract `B` items from `A` in a similar fashion.

Alternatively, you can go through the index items and subtract one item from another.